# Preventing user from returning to caller activity

Tags: android

I am writing a simple application where the mainActivity invokes a secondActivity. Is there a method I can use to prevent the user from simply pressing back to return to the calling activity?

Comment: Do you want to disable back key or you want to return to the main activity

Comment: You can override Activity.onBackPressed() to prevent users from returning back.

Comment: @Andy Can u show me how that would work?

Comment: @nemesis22 see my answer.. hope that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block back hardware key, put this to your SecondActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Blocks back button
}
```

If you want to close your FirstActivity so that users wont be able to visit it again, start your SecondActivity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
FirstActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your Second activity this way:

```
Intent secActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                secActivity.class);
        startActivity(secActivity);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: That way the MainActivity will still stay in the back stack.

Comment: Hi saran, but i think an activity gets removed from back stack once it's finish() method is called. Isn't it so...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to prevent the user to **ever** go back to the `mainActivity`, you should call the  `secondActivity` like this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  startActivity(intent);
```

That way pressing back will exit your application.

Comment: This doent seem to work. At the secondActivity i can still press back and it will go back to main

Comment: still doesnt work...overriding the onBackPressed() method in the secondActivity seems to be the best way